# What drawer that support flexbox can I use in replacement of @react-navigation/drawer within a react-native-web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am doing a [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) application using [expo SDK36](https://expo.io/).

I use [`@react-navigation/drawer`](https://github.com/react-navigation/drawer/) v5 for the native app, for the web, the gesture doesn't work so I need to replace it.

I have tried [`react-sidebar`](https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar), but their simplest example. I want to be able to `dock` the sidebar on large screen, as in this [example](http://balloob.github.io/react-sidebar/example/)

The issue I have with react-sidebar is that it mess up the flexbox when view use:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
function moveToBottom(component) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {component}
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 36
  }
})
export default moveToBottom
```

as described in [here](https://medium.com/react-native-training/position-element-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen-using-flexbox-in-react-native-a00b3790ca42).

What library that support this flexbox in views I can use to have a drawer that can be docked in `reactjs` (web)?